# Reading XML file in metrostyle application? possible?

Tags: file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using Windows 8 Developer Preview. I wish to develop an application that reads XML file. Is it possible? When I've tried to use `XDocument.Load(string uri)` it threw an access denied exception and there's no such class as `FileStream`. I know that metro style app are based on Silverlight which has no access to the file system, but it's actually a desktop app, so wouldn't I be able to read files? Is there any workaround? I'm pretty new to silverlight so maybe I just don't know the way?

Comment: Metro-style apps are in no way based on Silverlight. And do I assume correctly that you are using one of the .Net languages?

Comment: yup, I'm using xaml + c#

Comment: And there's another problem... why can't I access KnownFolder.DocumentsLibrary ? UnauthorizedException was thrown ;/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Metro application is sandboxed. You need to specify the capability to read files from Document library or from Removable storage, and associate specific types in your package manifest. Alternatively, you can use file picker, so that user specifically grants you access to some file.

Quote from [Access to user resources using the Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#removable_storage):

> The removableStorage capability provides programmatic access to files
> on removable storage, such as USB keys and external hard drives,
> filtered to the file type associations declared in the package
> manifest. For example, if a PDF reader app declared a .pdf file type
> association, it can open .pdf files on the removable storage device,
> but not other types of files.
>
> Care should be taken when declaring
> this capability, because users may include a variety of information in
> their removable storage devices, and look for a valid justification
> from the app.
>
> Alternatively, apps can use the file picker to access
> specific files on a removable storage device if they do not require
> full programmatic access.

Comment: Just double-click the Package.appxmanifest file, open the Declarations tab and add File Picker or File Type Associations from drop-down (with proper configuration for them).

Answer (score 5):

Read the answers by Ari Polsky to [this question at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/46a3088d-8420-485b-8697-8b2dda0f1f19/).

Basically, to access a file, you need permission to do so. To get that permission, either the user has to do that by choosing that file of folder it's in using one of the provided pickers.
Another option is to declare that you want to access some folder in your manifest. But this works only for “Library” locations.